# Laravel telegram bot sdk

Tags: laravel, sdk, telegram-bot

[image]

I have test command and I want to call or sent request this command inside my controller, pls help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call the PHP artisan command inside your controller using the following way.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

$project = TelegramBaza::select('name')->where('chat_id', $chatId)->first();
if($project && $project->name == 'ANORHOME'){

    //Call artisan command
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('message:send', [
        'user' => $user, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)